# Postgresql return NULL instead of right result in function

Tags: postgresql

I have function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.function_geoms()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  _geom_puwg1992 GEOMETRY := NEW.geom_puwg1992;
  _srid_puwg2000 INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT l.srid_puwg2000 INTO _srid_puwg2000 FROM locations l, geodesies g
    WHERE
      st_contains(l.geom_wgs84, g.geom_wgs84) AND
      g.well_id = NEW.well_id AND
      l.ancestry_depth = 1;
      
    RAISE NOTICE '%', _srid_puwg2000;
    
    IF (_geom_puwg1992 IS NOT NULL) THEN
      NEW.geom_puwg2000 := ST_TRANSFORM(_geom_puwg1992, _srid_puwg2000);
      NEW.geom_wgs84 := ST_TRANSFORM(_geom_puwg1992, 4326);
    END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;
```

Why raise notice returns NULL, instead of right result?

If if  run query:

```
SELECT l.srid_puwg2000 INTO _srid_puwg2000 FROM locations l, geodesies g
  WHERE
    st_contains(l.geom_wgs84, g.geom_wgs84) AND
    g.well_id = NEW.well_id AND
    l.ancestry_depth = 1;
```

it returns right result.

PostgreSQL 13

Best regards.

Comment: What statement does the trigger run on? How do you execute the standalone query?

Comment: In line NEW.geom_puwg2000 := ST_TRANSFORM(_geom_puwg1992, _srid_puwg2000);
_srid_puwg2000 is NULL, should be  integer 2160. If i run this select standalone, it returns right 2160.

Comment: Line NEW.geom_wgs84 := ST_TRANSFORM(_geom_puwg1992, 4326);  works perfect.

Comment: Please create a [mre].